# Public shower options in Munich?

Tags: germany, hygiene, munich, oktoberfest

Now that I've made sure that [sleeping in a parked car](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48669/is-it-legal-to-sleep-in-a-parked-car-on-the-streets-of-munich) is legal in Munich, I need to find a place to shower during our stay.

Is it possible to take a shower somewhere in Munich for less than 10EUR? Ideally the showers would be close to the Oktoberfest location.

Comment: There is a McClean at the central train station where you can shower. Don't know about the prices though. This is also pretty close to the Theresienwiese.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The City of Munich operates a number of indoor (and outdoor) swimming pools in and around Munich.  These pools are invariably fitted out with changing rooms and showers.  There is no need to go swimming if you only want to use the shower, but you will still have to pay the entrance fee.

You can peruse a list at [Statwerke Muenchen](http://www.swm.de/english/m-baeder/indoor-pools.html).

As for 'reasonable fee', swimming pools usually charge about EUR 5 to EUR 10, depending upon location and facilities available (e.g., sauna).

Comment: +1 Would they typically provide fresh towels (as I would expect at a health club) or do patrons bring their own?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, the municipal pools I used in Frankfurt had a surcharge of about EUR 1 or so.  Different city, same regime.  Also soap, and other accessories.

Comment: In the not-that-long-gone time when showers and baths in private homes were a rare luxury, most towns ran public baths for their residents. The need for this has mostly vanished, obviously, but a few larger cities still have (usually just one) such _Reinigungsbad_. Munich is among them; so the cheapest option is to visit _Müller'sches Volksbad_ and pay € 2,10 for 30 minutes in a private shower or € 3,30 for 45 minutes in a bathtub. Special opening hours apply.

Comment: @chirlu, great comment! It should be an answer so more people can see it

Comment: @chirlu *Bad* comment. That is a complete answer and *must* be posted as such. Remember that comments are second-class citizens on SE sites and hence by commenting instead of answering you are dooming useful information to be deleted.

Comment: @chirlu's awesome [info is actually available on the site](http://www.swm.de/english/m-baeder/indoor-pools/volksbad.html) linked to in this answer because it's one of the indoor pools operated by the city

Comment: @chirlu definitely post this as an answer.

Comment: Hm, a car wash might be cheaper ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - yeah, but the wax fogs up your glasses. :-)

Answer (score 15):

There are paid toilet and shower facilities located in the basement of munich central station. The service is provided by the private company *Mc Clean* and costs around 7€ for a shower including towel and a selection of soaps.

Opening hours are daily from 6am to 12pm.

Comment: IMO, this one should be the accepted answer.