# Breakfast places in Munich that open at 6AM or earlier on the weekends?

Tags: food-and-drink, restaurants, munich, oktoberfest, weekends

It seems that visitors should queue as early as 8AM in order to [get into the Oktoberfest tents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48724/how-early-should-i-get-to-the-oktoberfest-tents-to-get-in-without-a-reservation) on the weekends without a reservation.

This means breakfast must be completed before 7AM to leave enough time to get to Theresienwiese. Are there any breakfast places in Munich that open as early as 6AM?

By breakfast I mean a place that serves omeletes or porridge, or at least a salad along with donuts and coffee.

Comment: If you wanted to search the net, a good phrase is "frühstück oktoberfest muenchen"

Comment: @GayotFow found a couple of places, including one serving eggs. Thanks!

Comment: I think a bear and a chicken count as breakfast in Munich

Comment: Just as a side note: typical bavarian (and I guess thats why 99% of the people are going to the Oktoberfest...) would be to eat a _Weißwurstfrühstück_, constisting of a special kind of sausage (Weißwurst) and pretzel. I am quite sure this should be served in the tents as well and would allow you to get up later. Beware, I have never been to the Oktoberfest, so you might want to check.

Comment: @dirkk, I have been multiple times and yes, they are ubiquitous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a standardized American breakfast:

- McDonald's, Im Tal 6 (near Marienplatz) opens at 6:00; Hauptbahnhof (downstairs near S-Bahn) open 24/7.
- Burger King, twice at Hauptbahnhof, open 24/7.
- Starbucks, Hauptbahnhof, opens at 3:30.

Comment: +1, great answer; there's ample McDonald's etc all over Munich.

Comment: yes, but many McDonald's open at 7 or later; forgot the one at Hauptbahnhof, but that's a small one :-)

Answer (score 6):

After some searching on Foursquare and Google Maps I've found the following places:

### Sultan Backparadies

Open from **6AM to 10PM** and located 800 meters from the heart of Oktoberfest. The address is [Goethestraße 40](https://goo.gl/maps/zUg2I). Judging by the [photos](https://foursquare.com/v/sultan-backparadies/4bfeafc9e584c92855116d25/photos), the place serves eggs, salad, sandwiches and a variety of bakery.

### Dunkin Donuts

Open 24 hours per day and located near Munich Ostbahnhof, 4 km from Oktoberfest. The address is: [Orleansplatz 10](https://goo.gl/maps/AsGIw). The [menu](https://foursquare.com/v/dunkin-donuts/53428b06498ebef659157134/photos) includes donuts and coffee, for about 1EUR per donut.

Comment: Aaaaaah doughnuts and beer. When in Germany... :)

Comment: Notwithstanding an opening time of 6AM, did you check to be sure that they serve cooked food at that hour?

Comment: @GayotFow I assume so, at least I've never been in a restaurant that doesn't serve food at opening time. I'll check it out myself this September.