# What kind of food is served inside the Oktoberfest tents and at what price?

Tags: food-and-drink, price, munich, events, oktoberfest

I'm trying to budget a multi-day trip to Oktoberfest and I'm unable to find the tents' food menu for last year. The beers were priced at ~10EUR, as mentioned by [multiple](http://www.thelocal.de/20150407/oktoberfest-beer-prices-shoot-over-10) websites, but nobody seems to mention the food. So the questions are:

1. What food is served inside the Oktoberfest tents?
2. What are the prices?
3. Are there any vegetarian options?

Ideally someone would just post a picture of last year's menu.

Comment: Typical Bavarian food I would guess. The menu is bound to be tent-dependent though.

Comment: Sausages and hot sauerkraut were my favorites.  Had gingerbread and hot smoked fish outsided.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bratwurst

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Munich native again.

1. Of course all tents serve typical Bavarian food. The food can be roughly divided into two categories: warm dishes and proper starters/desserts as served in any Bavarian restaurant and *Brotzeit*, a German/Bavarian classic consisting of bread or *Brezn* (pretzel) with various spreads, hearty toppings and often accompanied by some kind of radish. Many tents serve special dishes matching their motto. Such as different Ox dishes in the *Ochsenbraterei*, *Steckerlfisch* (fish on a stick) at *Fischers Vroni*, grilled ducks at the *Entenbraterei* and *Knödel* (dunmplings) at the *Knödelei*. Just to mention some of them. Besides those special dishes you should always get *Hendl* (grilled chicken) and *Schweinsbraten* (roast pork) as warm dishes.
2. Prices vary by time of day: there are special deals for lunch, while dinner is certainly more expensive. For lunch you can calculate with deals starting at about 10€ while warm dinner ranges from 15 to 25 Euros. *Brotzeit* is also priced around 10€. Of course the sky is the limit and you'll also find dishes on the menu with significant higher prices.
3. All tents do also serve vegetarian dishes often priced between 10 and 15 Euros. But the real *Schmankerl* (delicacies) are typically not vegetarian. You might instead want to try a sweet course as a main dish. The Austrian influence is strong in this area and results in great dishes.

Some menus from last year can be found here (not all containig prices and none in English):

- [Hofbräu](http://www.hb-festzelt.de/speisekarte.html)
- [Schützenzelt](https://www.schuetzenfestzelt.com/speisekarte)
- [Weinzelt](https://www.weinzelt.com/global/downloads/Kufflers-Weinzelt_Speisenkarte_2018_D.pdf)
- [Winzerer Fähndl](http://www.winzerer-faehndl.com/kueche_speisenkarte.html)
- [Fischer Vroni](https://www.fischer-vroni.de/index.php/speisekarte.html)
- [Augustiner](http://www.festhalle-augustiner.com/html/kuche.html)

And yes, the beer price has surpassed the 10€ barrier. A *Bediengeld* (the waitress share) is already included, but additional tipping is still expected!

Comment: [Looks like the waitresses earn a lot of money](http://cdn.rsvlts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Oktoberfest-2012-pictures-81.jpg)

Comment: @CountIblis looks like she deserves the tips, given a Mass is probably 1-2kg each :)

Comment: That's all foam!

Comment: @CountIblis A Mass is even heavier, as the mug itself already weighs 1.3kg plus an additional kilo for the beer.

Comment: @CountIblis Yes they certainly earn a lot of money during those 16 days. Income ranges from 5000 to 10000 Euro. But this impressive pile of money is really justifieid given the fact that waitresses work 13 hours a day for 16 days in a row, carrying several tons of filled beer mugs,

Comment: @JoErNanO There a strict laws defining how much beer has to be in each mug. There is a measuring line on each mug indicating the amount of one liter. The actual filling level must not lie more than 14 millimetres underneath this line. Unfortunately some studies have shown that depending on the tent some mugs contain just around 0.7 litres.